# How to build a GUI toolkit from scartch

Tags: c, user-interface, operating-system

I've been chosen to spearhead the construction of an OS from scratch by my firm. In terms of OS basic functionality i'm cool, but I have quite an issue on UI design. How do engineers design UIs all from scratch? e.g. the Mac OSX UI is different from Windows UI and also Unix-like OS's all have different-looking UIs. I have an idea that it might involve C programming but how do engineers define these graphics, their looks plus their interactivity on user-initiated events, are there any libraries that i might not be aware of? 
Thanks

Comment: Start with the very basics: rectangles. As soon as you got that working, you (but preferably a graphic artst) can skin it any way you like. Most of the eye candy on the systems you list are just that: eye candy. Shadows, highlights, semi-transparent windows all have no "meaning" -- either they are buttons or they are not.

Comment: thanks for that, but how do i actually draw these rectangles? using openGL?

Comment: That should be irrelevant to your code. These 'rectangles' live in memory only. You *may* draw them any way you like (including, but not limited to, drawing libs such as Cairo, OpenGL or ncurses) but the underlying code should be robust enough to work with *any* form of drawing -- just like it should (theoretically, that is...) best be resolution-independent.

Comment: if stackoverflow had a like button, I would've liked your reply thanks

Comment: I'm curious, what platform are you targeting and why do none of the available OS'es suit you needs? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't build the entire stack from scratch - you are much better off leveraging on at least low-level 2D graphics to ensure good performance. For example for UNIX based systems, you'd use *Xlib* primitives to build your windowing toolkit on top of it. Use that and lay your abstractions on top of it.

But again, in this time and age it is much better to use an existing toolkit and at worst port the underlying layer to your OS.

Comment: i just checked the xlib primitives online, that solves 99% if not 100% of my problems. Gracias

Comment: i also have to mention about the Cairo vector graphics, they're too, cool enough for the job